# SQL query for finding the first, second and third highest numbers

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

What is an example query to retrieve the first, second and third largest number from a database table using SQL Server?

Answer (score 9):

You can sort by your value descendingly and take the top 3.

```
SELECT TOP 3 YourVal FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourVal DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you wanted each result separate,

first number :

```
SELECT TOP 1 YourVal FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourVal DESC
```

second number:

```
SELECT TOP 1 YourVal FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourVal not in (SELECT TOP 1 YourVal FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourVal DESC)
ORDER BY YourVal DESC
```

third number:

```
SELECT TOP 1 YourVal FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourVal not in (SELECT TOP 2 YourVal FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourVal DESC)
ORDER BY YourVal DESC
```

assuming YourVal is unique

---

EDIT : following on from OPs comment

to get the nth value, select the TOP 1 that isn't in the TOP (n-1), so fifth can be chosen by:

```
SELECT TOP 1 YourVal FROM YourTable 
WHERE YourVal not in (SELECT TOP 4 YourVal FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourVal DESC)
ORDER BY YourVal DESC
```

Comment: thankjs for ur help...but agin iam having one doubt that how can u retrive only the 5th highest value of a column from the table

Answer (score 1):

The proposed `SELECT TOP n ... ORDER BY key` will work but you need to be aware of the fact that you might get unexpected results if the column you're sorting on is not unique. Find more information on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305325/should-sql-ranking-functionality-be-considered-as-use-with-caution).

Answer (score 1):

Sudhakar,

It may be easier to use ROW_NUMBER() or DENSE_RANK() for some of these questions. For example, to find YourVal and other columns from the fifth row in order of YourVal DESC:

```
WITH TRanked AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      ORDER BY YourVal DESC, yourPrimaryKey
    ) AS rk
)
  SELECT YourVal, otherColumns
  FROM TRanked
  WHERE rk = 5;
```

If you want all rows with the fifth largest distinct YourVal value, just change ROW_NUMBER() to DENSE_RANK().

One *really big* advantage to these functions is the fact that you can immediately change a "the nth highest YourVal" query to a "the nth highest YourVal **for each otherColumn**" query just by adding PARTITION BY otherColumn to the OVER clause.

Answer (score 1):

In certain DBMS packages the `top` command may not work. Then how to do this? Suppose we need to find the 3rd largest salary in employee table. So we select the distinct salary from the table in descending order:

```
select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc
```

Now among the salaries selected we need top 3 salaries, for that we write:

```
select salary from (select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc) where rownum<=3 order by salary
```

This gives top 3 salaries in ascending order. This makes the third largest salary to go to first position. Now we have the final task of printing the 3rd largest number.

```
select salary from (select salary from (select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc) where rownum<=3 order by salary) where rownum=1
```

This gives the third largest number. For any mistake in the query please let me know. Basically to get the nth largest number we can rewrite the above query as

```
select salary from (select salary from (select distinct salary from employee order by salary desc) where rownum<=**n** order by salary) where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table called Orders and 3 columns Id, ProductId and Quantity then to retrieve the top 3 highest quantities your query would look like:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [Id], [ProductId], [Quantity] FROM [Orders] ORDER BY [Quantity] DESC
```

or if you just want the quantity column:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [Quantity] FROM [Orders] ORDER BY [Quantity] DESC
```

Comment: yeah my bad, so exhausted and rushed didnt stop to think. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

This works prefect!

```
select top 1 * from Employees where EmpId in 
(
    select top 3 EmpId from Employees order by EmpId
) order by EmpId desc;
```

If you would like to get 2nd, 3rd or 4th highest just change `top3` to appropriate number.